# Error in opening Spyder Ubuntu

Tags: python, spyder, attributeerror

When I click on the icon for Spyder 2.7, the icon appears on the launcher and disappears soon. I'd installed using In the terminal, when spyder is typed, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 3, in <module>
    start_app.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/start_app.py", line 114, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 155, in <module>
    from spyderlib.utils.environ import WinUserEnvDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/utils/environ.py", line 17, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.dicteditor import DictEditor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/dicteditor.py", line 39, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.dicteditorutils import (sort_against, get_size,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/dicteditorutils.py", line 78, in <module>
    import bs4
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_base'
```

I tried updating html5lib and beautifulsoup to the required versions but did not help. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade to `pip install --upgrade html5lib==1.0b8` if upgrading didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This line in your error

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/start_app.py
```

means that you're using a very, *very* old Spyder version (**2.3**, released three years ago).

Our recommendation to get our latest version (**3.2.8**) is to download and install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux), instead of using the packages from your Linux distribution (which can be terrible outdated, like in this case).

Comment: This problem came after I "deep cleaned" (finding each and every file of spyder and deleting it, so that the reinstalled version doesn't have the old settings, configuration, memory, etc.) spyder and reinstalled it. Spyder3 is working fine by the same process of installation. This https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html seems not working. The same error. Can you tell me how to download and install the latest version (both ways, with anaconda and standalone)?

Comment: For Anaconda, please download and install it using the link in my answer. It comes with Spyder and a lot more of scientific packages. For `pip`, you need to run `pip install spyder` in a Python 3 virtualenv. That's because PyQt5 is not available for Python 2.

Comment: I already have Anaconda installed, not by this link. How do I install the latest spyder on my Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: This is without python console. For standalone, i.e., without anaconda, how to install Spyder?

Comment: `pip install -U spyder`

Comment: How to uninstall spyder with all its settings, so that when I reinstall all the settings are default as in a virgin installation.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I have fixed this issue. But I'm facing another issue. When I run by terminal typing "spyder", it is launched perfectly but when I try to launch it by GUI, clicking on the icon, nothing happens, no error message is also displayed. What is the issue and how to resolve it?